# Name the output of an expression in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I wonder whether it's possible to give a name to the output of a certain expression to retrieve it from the graph at another part of the code.

For example

```
def A(a, b):
    c = a + b
    d = d * a
return d
```

For debug purposes it would be nice if I could pull out `c` at another position without returning it through the entire function hierarchy.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming `a` and `b` are tensors.

Either you give a name to `c` using `tf.identity`

```
def A(a, b):
    c = a + b
    c = tf.identity(c, name = "c")
    d = d * a
return d
```

Either you use the `tf.add` operation instead of `+`:

```
def A(a, b):
    tf.add(a, b, name = "c")
    d = d * a
return d
```

Either way, you get retrieve `c` with `tf.get_variable('c:0')` (You might need to precise the scope if any.)

Comment: shouldn't this be `c = tf.identity(c, name = "c")` ?

Comment: Right, it should