# Tensorflow: Naming variables

Tags: python, tensorflow, naming-conventions

I'm wondering where to put the following function and how to name the variables "r" and "p":

```py
def fit_mme(sample_data, name=None):
    """
        Calculates the Maximum-of-Momentum Estimator of NB(r, p) for a given NxM matrix `sample_data`

        :param sample_data: `(N, M)` matrix with `M` distributions containing `N` observed values each
        :return: estimated values of `r` and `p`
        """
    with tf.name_scope(name, "MME"):
        mean = tf.reduce_mean(sample_data, axis=0, name="mean")
        variance = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(sample_data - mean),
                                  axis=0,
                                  name="variance")
        nan = tf.fill(tf.shape(variance), math.nan, name="NaN_constant")

        r_by_mean = tf.where(tf.less(mean, variance),
                             mean / (variance - mean),
                             nan)
        r = r_by_mean * mean
        p = 1 / (r_by_mean + 1)
        return r, p
```

As you can see, I already named "mean", "variance" and "nan", but how can I name the variables "r" and "p"?

Also, should i pack this method into a sub-class of "tf.contrib.distributions.NegativeBinomial" or should I create some utils.py file for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can either do:

```
r = tf.multiply(r_by_mean, mean, name = 'r')
```

and

```
p = tf.divide(1, tf.add(r_by_mean, 1), name = 'p')
```

or you can (as suggested in [Name the output of an expression in Tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47030369) ):

```
r = r_by_mean * mean
r = tf.identity(r, name = 'r')
```

and

```
p = 1 / (r_by_mean + 1)
p = tf.identity(p, name = 'p')
```

> Also, should i pack this method into a sub-class of "tf.contrib.distributions.NegativeBinomial" or should I create some utils.py file for it?

I would not put it into any 'official' namespace such as tf but use your own file such that it is clear that this is functionality added by you / your project and not by Tensorflow (unless you need to fix / override some standard tensorflow functionality).

Comment: With "sub-class of NegativeBinomial" I meant "creating my own NegativeBinomial class inheriting tf.contrib.distributions.NegativeBinomial".
I'm still not sure, how I should organize my project to keep things clearly structured; e.g. "fit_mme" is some kind of optimization method for NB distributions, but creating a "NegativeBinomialEstimator" with the estimator API does not make sense, since I do not want to predict any data.